# How to make the Tool not .NET module

Tags: .net, module, makefile

I made a program with C#. it's a windows application. Then I used .NET Reflector and it decompiled it but I got another program it can't decompile it because its not a .NET module so how can I make my tool like that I don't want anyone to decompile my tool. Is there any way to do that ?

Comment: You can't prevent someone from reverse-engineering your application.  You can only make it more difficult.  In your case, you've already answered your own question; if you don't want someone to disassemble your application with Reflector, then use something other than .NET to write your application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you write a program in a .NET language and compile it, its only pseudo-compiled. It's more complex than I can write here but it's sitting in an intermediate language.

When the computer runs the .NET program it converts it to machine language *on the fly* which is needed to run on the computer.

Other languages such as C++ are compiled to pretty close to machine language. This makes the program less portable. But it's very difficult to reverses engineer C++ programs compared to C# / .NET.

Now, if you are writing a program on .NET that you don't want reverse engineered, your best bet is an [obfuscator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_obfuscators_for_.NET) which makes it very difficult to read the code -- but it's not impossible for someone to figure the code out. It just takes more work. For example, a function that was called `openWindow` would be renamed to just `a`.

Anyway. This is a pretty big topic but the important take away is that since .NET is only partially compiled, it will always be possible to re-convert the compiled code back to C# (or VB.net for that matter) -- even obfuscated code can be un-done.

So, to directly answer your question, you can't take a compiled .NET program and further compile it so it's to the level of a C++ program.

Answer (score 0):

You should use an obfuscator like: http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/smartassembly